# Accessing a property after Seq.find()

Tags: f#

Probably a very simple question - if I have a sequence of objects, on which I run `Seq.find()` to return a single element, how do I then access one property without storing the whole element as a variable?

e.g.

```
type MyType = { Id : int; Text : string }
let obs = [| { Id = 1; Text = "Hello" }; { Id = 2; Text = "Goodbye" } |] :> seq<MyType>

let getFirstText (array : seq<MyType>) = 
  array |> Seq.find(fun mt -> mt.Id = 1) |> .Text
                                            ^^^^^  
getFirstText obs |> printfn "%s"
```

This gives *Unexpected symbol '.' in expression*.

Trying `Seq.find(fun mt -> mt.Id = 1).Text` gives a *Type constraint mismatch* - *The type ''a -> MyType' is not compatible with the type 'MyType'* on line 6.

You can't use `Seq.Map()` as the object being passed is no longer a sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you can use parens:

```
(array |> Seq.find(fun mt -> mt.Id = 1)).Text
```

or lambda abstraction:

```
array |> Seq.find(fun mt -> mt.Id = 1) |> (fun mt -> mt.Text)
```

Another way would be to use pick function and then you define `mt` symbol once:

```
array |> Seq.pick (fun mt -> if mt.Id = 1 then Some my.Text else None)
```